# Assigning a value to a "local" variable with M2Doc

Tags: m2doc

I need to do the following, but I am struggling.

1. I declare a variable to false
2. I start a for loop that includes an if statement. If this statement is evaluated at true during one of the loops, I want to assign true to my variable.

I have tried to use a let construct, but 1. I am not sure this is the proper way to achieve what I want and 2. I am not sure about the syntax for changing the value of my variable.

```
{m:let test=false}
   {m:for x|...}
      {m:if aStatement=true}
         {m:test=true}    // this line does not work, the syntax is probably wrong
      {m:endif}
   {m:endfor}
{m:endlet}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Given the anwers provided, I am putting my original code hereunder, with the original mistake of believing I could change the value of a variable, because I struggle understanding the instructions. Would you be able to indicate me whether 1. the let construct is the right thing to use and 2. what should be in me let statement?

```
{m:let test = false}

{m:for req | PIDSREQ.eAllContents()->filter(Requirements::Requirement)} 
   {m:for allocreq | req.eContents()->filter(CapellaRequirements::CapellaIncomingRelation)}
      {m:if allocreq.target=SF}
         {m:test = true}
      {m:endif} 
   {m:endfor}
{m:endfor}

{m:if test = false}
NO REQUIREMENTS
{m:endif}

{m:endlet}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Variables are immutable in M2Doc, you need to use an [AQL](https://eclipse.dev/acceleo/documentation/aql.html) expression instead:

```
let test = aCollection->any(e | e.expression) <> null
```

The any() service returns the first element that matches the given expression. Then we test is such element is not null.

Comment: Thank you very much. To be sure to understand, instead of changing my variable from false to true, I will simply add any element to aCollection and test whether it is null or not. Right?

Comment: Yes, the collection you use in the for loop. You can then remove the for loop and directly use the test variable.

Comment: I understand the principle but I am not successful trying to implement it. When I insert the line {m:let test = aCollection->any(e | e.expression) <> null} in my template, I get the following message: Invalid let statement: Couldn't find the 'aCollection' variableInvalid let statement: Couldn't find the 'aCollection' variable.

Comment: aCollection should be replaced with the for expression you are using (... in your example).

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. I've edited the post with my original code to try and be more specific about what I am trying to do.

Comment: According to your example if should look like: let test = PIDSREQ.eAllContents()->filter(Requirements::Requirement).eContents()->filter(CapellaRequirements::CapellaIncomingRelation)->any(ir | ir.target=SF) <> null

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!